# A transactional log backup could not be generated because database is in either NORECOVERY mode or STANDBY mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

We have configured Always on Group Database with Full Recovery mode and secondary replica is in sync mode with primary server.Now we have configured logshipping in primary server to supply t-log backups to DR site.Always on group backup preference is set to primary.While executing job its showing success but no t-log backup file is being generated in share folder.In error logs there is a message showing as:

> A transactional log backup could not be generated because database is in either NORECOVERY mode or STANDBY mode

Can anyone help me out with this?

[image: img]

Comment: It seems to me that there is a problem with backup preference in AlwaysOn. Try changing it to see if it works. Also, you may need to consider AlwaysOn failover scenario for log-shipping to work.

Comment: Backup preference is set to primary database and failover hasn't yet occurred as we are testing this on primary replica.First time we have configured logshipping in primary replica and there are no previous t-log backups.

Comment: If you explain how you set up your backup preference, folks might be able to see if anything is missed.

Comment: The Norecovery/Standby error can only happen if the target of the Backup Log command is your secondary...check your settings.   Is the Log Shipping backup job the only thing doing log backups?  I've seen a lot of setups where LS and some other process (Maintenance Plan, Ola, etc.) were in conflict

Comment: No even we have a maintenance plan setup which takes t-log backups  and backup is set to primary  @Kevin3NF

Comment: Something is trying to back up the secondary replica or LS destination....because your LS Source/AG Primary CANT be in Norecovery/Standby :)

Comment: What if i change always on backup preference to any replica..? and Info in Error log:Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'XYZ'  2017-05-22 06:30:15.82
A transactional log backup could not be generated because the database is in either NORECOVERY mode or STANDBY mode. Primary Database: 'XYZ'  2017-05-22 06:30:15.82
----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG BACKUP   -----    Exit Status: 0 (Success).  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded  @Kevin3NF